# Is it bad practice to have two separate MEF plugin containers?

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

Let's say I have a class (not a static class), `A`, that in some way uses plugins. I use MEF to manage those plugins, and add methods for my users to add parts catalogs. Example usage:

```
var myA = new A();
myA.LoadPlugins(new DirectoryCatalog("path/to/plugins"));
myA.DoStuffWithPlugins();
```

In the same namespace as `A` is class `B`. `B` also uses MEF to manage plugins, and has its own `CompositionContainer`. If a user wants to interact with `B`'s plugins, she must use `B`'s plugin management methods.

`B` is used just like `A` is, above.

My question is, is this bad? Should I care that there are two separate places to load plugins in my namespace? If it is bad, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is this bad? Should I care that there are two separate places to load plugins in my namespace? If it is bad, what are the alternatives?

Not necessarily.  There is no reason you can't have two completely separate compositions within the same application.

That being said, there's also no real reason, in most cases, to have more than a single composition.  MEF will compose both sets of data at once.  In your case, you could compose your importers and your reports with the same composition container, which would have the advantage of allowing somebody who is extending your system to only create a single assembly which extends both portions of your application.

One potential minor red flag here is that these are two separate types within the same namespace, but each of which have their own plugin system.  Typically, a framework with a full plugin system is going to be complex enough that I'd question whether they belong in the same namespace - though from going by type names of "A" and "B" it's impossible to know whether this is truly inappropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I probably could have been more descriptive with my class names :). Class A is basically an importer of files. The plugins it uses are file format filters. Class B takes the output from a class A instance and generates a report. Class B's plugins are file writers to support different report formats (HTML, txt, docx, etc.)

Comment: @SimpleCoder And, even given that, I would probably have an `Import` and a `Reporting` namespace, or something like that...

Comment: There is a top-level namespace, MyProject which is divided further into Core and PluginFramework. Import and Reporting classes are contained in Core. Do you think I should split Core further?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I'd probably have MyProject with Import + Reporting + PluginFramework... Also, there's no real reason to have two separate imports, the single composition can compose your reports AND your importers...

Comment: @SimpleCoder I just edited my answer to include more details on that last statement.

Comment: Interesting. Where would my composition container go then? Right now, it's a private property of each of my classes.

Comment: @SimpleCoder You could have it be private in your PluginFramework - and compose the entire application at once...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12629/discussion-between-reed-copsey-and-simplecoder)

Comment: One more thing I forgot to ask: With the new unified plugin system we discussed, is it ok if I keep both classes in the same namespace? I propose MyProject.Core, which contains Importer, Reporter, and PluginManager (the singleton). Then, MyProject.PluginFramework contains IImporter, IReporter, etc. Or should I separate it another way?

Comment: @SimpleCoder You can organize it any way you choose.  I'd personally separate out IImport from IReport, since they're such completely different functionalities, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with that. I would recommend a base class for `class A` and `class B` to reuse methods.

```
class A : BaseCompositionClass {
    //    implementations
}

class B : BaseCompositionClass {

    //    implementations
}
```

You could use a single [`CatalogExportProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.catalogexportprovider) and then query that provider for the matching imports and exports. You could then use a single `CompositionFactory` from which `classA` and `classB` request compositions.